# Proof that stages $V_{\alpha}$ are well-ordered?

Tags: set-theory

To show that stages are well-ordered, I want to prove that ordinals and stages, ordered by $\in$, are isomorphic.

My textbook proves that $\alpha \in \beta \to V_\alpha \in V_\beta$. For the converse, suppose that $V_\alpha \in V_\beta \land \alpha \notin \beta$, and we will work towards a contradiction. Trichotomy states that for all ordinals $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha \in \beta \lor \beta \in \alpha \lor \alpha = \beta$. The first disjunct is ruled out by our premise. The third is ruled out by the fact that $V_\alpha \notin V_\alpha$ for all stages (as proved in my textbook). And if $\beta \in \alpha$, then $V_\beta \in V_\alpha$, which implies $V_\beta \subseteq V_\alpha$. As the premise implies $V_\alpha \subseteq V_\beta$, we have $V_\alpha = V_\beta$, which implies a contradiction again, in a similar manner.

So, we have $\alpha \in \beta \leftrightarrow V_\alpha \in V_\beta$. What remains to be show is that there exists a bijection $V \colon \text{ON} \to \text{Stages}$. But such a function can't be constructed in $\mathsf{ZF}$, since $\text{ON}$ is a proper class. It seems like the most we can do is prove a formula which says the same thing as a function $V$ existing. By transfinite recursion, there exists $V_\alpha$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ and if $\alpha = \beta$, then $V_\alpha = V_\beta$, making $V$ a "function." Since stages are defined by ordinals, our "function" is surjective. Suppose that $V_\alpha = V_\beta \land \alpha \neq \beta$. Then $\beta \in \alpha$ or $\alpha \in \beta$ by Trichotomy, which implies $V_\alpha \in V_\beta$ or $V_\beta \in V_\alpha$ and hence $V_\alpha \in V_\alpha$, a falsehood. So, the "function" $V$ is bijective.

Is my proof thorough enough, or are there any gaps? Thank you.

Comment: Could you state your definition of $V_\alpha$? The standard definition of $V_\alpha$ is given by recursion on $\alpha$, so $V_\alpha$ is defined for all ordinals by principle.

Comment: Furthermore, you can simplify your argument by using that $V_\alpha\cap \mathrm{Ord}=\alpha$: thus $V_\alpha\in V_\beta$ implies $\alpha\subseteq\beta$. We can exclude $\alpha=\beta$ since $V_\alpha\notin V_\alpha$.